# How can we remove html tag by using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can we remove html tag by using Jquery e.g we have this html

```
<div><dd>hello world</dd></div>
```

i want to remove `<dd>` tag and produce this output

```
<div>hello world</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove just the opening tag? Or the opening and closing tags?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), for example:

```
$("dd").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vZcT7/).

Comment: i checked it but it remove also contents which is in dd tag that is "Hello wolrd"

Comment: @user438860 - It shouldn't do that unless you're in a browser that doesn't support the HTML5 `<dd>` tag (IE perhaps?) In that case you need something like html5shiv: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: $("div").html(function(i, h){ return $(h).text(); });
this realy works thanks

Answer (score 1):

To remove all child nodes, retaining only the text, could also try:

```
$("div").html(function(i, h){ return $(h).text(); });
```

[I forked @Nick Craver's jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/miles/BCWyU/).

Answer (score 0):

here's what I use.  though mind you this works only if you give the div a class (or id).

```
var string = $('div.test').html().replace('<dd>', '').replace('</dd>', '')
$('div.test').html(string);
```

What this will do is simply put the contents of the div into a variable (with .html() you grab not just the text but all the html) and then strip out the dd tags, then repopulate the

edit:

here's a better way to do it actually.  using this code you don't have to rely on a class or id being present for the div.

```
    container = $('div').find('dd').parent();
    var test = container.html().replace('<dd>', '').replace('</dd>', '')
    container.html(test);
```

Comment: see my edit, I changed it so that you don't need to use a class (incase you don't have access to it, since you don't seem to have access to remove the dd?

Answer (score 0):

You could always make an if statement that checks to see if a div contains one dd  element inside of it, then if that's the case, copy the contents from the dd, remove the dd element, then inject the contents into the div.

I don't know javascript that much, but assuming you use the right object and some simple algorithm, anything can be done!